# append xml-files in html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

when i have a website with a lot of text, i think its a good way to store them outside and make this with xml files (despite cms, i guess this would be the best) but i dont have as much experience with parsing xml files in html.
lets say i have a div `<div id="content_1"> </div>` in this div i want to add lots of text and a `<p id="content_1_text"></p>` on it.
how can i do something like `$('#content_1').append('<p id="content_1_text"> ... XML HERE ...</p>');`
And that in its best way! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store large amounts of text would be in a database. jQuery does have an [XML library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), but best practices today are more along the lines of using a database, and sending/receiving JSON.